# Secondary Hard Drive is not detected

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

I have a acer A515 laptop and I have 128 ssd and 1TB hdd , I installed ubuntu(20.04) on ssd, After installation completed successfully and system runs I cannot find my 1TB hdd
I checked with Gparted and it is also showing only 128ssd.

[ls -la /dev/sd*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMMtw.png)
[mount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oQxt.png)
[lsblk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwfIS.png)

Comment: Please run the following commads and post the output here: ls -la /dev/sd* ls -la /dev/hd* mount lsblk This will help to diagnose the problem

Comment: how did you install ubuntu? Did you run complete installation or "something else" to configure both drives? I had the same issue this week and followed this tutorial:
https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/installing-ubuntu-two-hard-drives Worked perfectly.

Comment: I choosed erase disk and install ubuntu

Comment: I try to reinstall again using the tutorial https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/installing-ubuntu-two-hard-drives but during the installation I cannot detect the my hdd.(I can detect my hdd in bios setup)